# How to change fields in Angular dynamic

Tags: javascript, jquery, angularjs, angularjs-scope, steroids

I have a really simple question I have been asking many times before in different ways without getting the help I needed. So Im familiar with javascript and HTML, but a real noob when it comes to Angular and steroids. I have provided code in all my other question, but this time I want to try to just provide some pictures to illustrate my problem, and then maybe you guys have a smarter solution that what I think is possible.

So it's quite easy. The user starts in view 1 (the first picture) and based on his/her choice he/she will be forwarded to the next view (picture 2). If the user clicks on the list element Button 1, he/she will be forwarded to picture two with the check boxes Button 1.1, Button 1.2 and Button 1.3. However, if he/she clicks on Button 2 in view 1 (the first picture), he/she should be forwarded to the same view (picture 2) as when he/she clicks on Button 1, only this time the values of the checkboxes should be Button 2.1, Button 2.2 and Button 2.3. How is this possible?? I use scope, I would like to change it dynamic, but after 1000 tries I have given that up and I would just see a solution work. Please help

[image: View 1]

[image: View 2]

**UPDATED WITH CODE**
Ok so I added som code to this post, but please show be a working solution. The code example is almost the same as described above except some small differences. When you click on Button 1 in index1.html, the user should be forwarded to index2.html and the scope value should be button1. If the user clicks on button2, the scope value should be button2. However, the scope value stay static and does not change from the origin value which is "index 2". The reason why I did not provide the code in the first case was because I just want a solution that shows the first picture below and by clicking on one of the options the user will come to the next view (picture 2), and see the checkbox values based on which button he/she clicks. I do not want to create three html pages in order to show the different values for each button, I want to change the values dynamically. How is that possible??? Se the code below.

**Index.html**

```
    <!DOCTYPE html>
<html ng-app="plunker">

  <head>
    <meta charset="utf-8" />
    <title>AngularJS Plunker</title>
    <script>document.write('<base href="' + document.location + '" />');</script>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="style.css" />
    <script data-require="angular.js@1.3.x" src="https://code.angularjs.org/1.3.12/angular.js" data-semver="1.3.12"></script>
    <script src="app.js"></script>
  </head>

  <body>
<div ng-controller="IndexController">
      <a class="item" href="#" ng-click="button1()">
        Button1
      </a>
      <br> <br>
      <a class="item" href="#" ng-click="button2()">
        Button2
      </a>
</div>
  </body>
</html>
```

**Index2.html**

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html ng-app="plunker">

  <head>
    <meta charset="utf-8" />
    <title>AngularJS Plunker</title>
    <script>document.write('<base href="' + document.location + '" />');</script>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="style.css" />
    <script data-require="angular.js@1.3.x" src="https://code.angularjs.org/1.3.12/angular.js" data-semver="1.3.12"></script>
    <script src="app.js"></script>
  </head>

  <body>
<div ng-app="plunker" ng-controller="IndexController2" >

<b> {{Test}} </b>

</div>
  </body>
</html>
```

**app.js**

```
var app = angular.module('plunker', []);

app.controller('IndexController', function($scope, $rootScope) {  




     $scope.button1 = function(){   
       console.log("inside button1");
 $scope.Test = "Button1";

        // The code to change the view from Index.html to index2.html
        /*  var view = new supersonic.ui.View("legeApp#helsePlagerOrer");
            //supersonic.ui.layers.push(view);
            var customAnimation = supersonic.ui.animate("flipHorizontalFromLeft");
            supersonic.ui.layers.push(view, { animation: customAnimation });*/
        };

     $scope.button2 = function(){   
       console.log("inside button2");
        $scope.Test = "Button2";

            // The code to change the view from Index.html to index2.html
        /*  var view = new supersonic.ui.View("legeApp#helsePlagerNese");
            //supersonic.ui.layers.push(view);
            var customAnimation = supersonic.ui.animate("flipHorizontalFromLeft");
            supersonic.ui.layers.push(view, { animation: customAnimation });*/
        };

    });

    app.controller('IndexController2', function($scope, $rootScope) {   
      $scope.Test = "index 2";
    });
```

Comment: Can you also add the code you have tried so far? The mockups are nice, but don't get us very far without your actual working code.

Comment: Ok I updated my post, but it does not mather for me what code I'm using as long as what I'm trying works. I just want to show different text based on which button the user clicks on, and I do not want to create a html page for each time the text should be different.

Comment: Is there a reason you have two separate index.html-pages? Usually you do page transitions with Angular router in client side.

Comment: No it's know, I open for any suggestions. I created two html pages because that is what I'm used to when I develop in Javascript. Can you show me a solution?